# how to access object array as show in code

Tags: php

how to access each file name...

```
 {"Appointments":
    [
        {
            "file_name":"eeea4a560492004c5c14f9414e88c32c.jpg", 
            "file_type":"image\/jpeg", 
            "file_path":"C:\/inetpub\/wwwroot\/nautSearch\/server\/uploadedfiles\/files\/", 
            "orig_name":"a46cf6866df6f358bece629ef472ac69.jpg", 
            "file_ext":".jpg", 
            "file_size":418.17, 
            "is_image":true, 
            "image_width":2560, 
            "image_height":1440, 
            "image_type":"jpeg", 
            "image_size_str":"width=\"2560\" height=\"1440\""

        }, 
        {
            "file_name":"c08ff85a44e0f86ab48ec709e6ba1b4a.jpg", 
            "file_type":"image\/jpeg", 
            "file_path":"C:\/inetpub\/wwwroot\/nautSearch\/server\/uploadedfiles\/files\/", 
            "file_ext":".jpg", 
            "file_size":27.38, 
            "is_image":true, 
            "image_width":479, 
            "image_height":403, 
            "image_type":"jpeg", 
            "image_size_str":"width=\"479\" height=\"403\""

        }, 
        {
            "file_name":"4536acd0479c6c5dee3b1f546ed8d328.jpg", 
            "file_type":"image\/jpeg", 
            "file_path":"C:\/inetpub\/wwwroot\/nautSearch\/server\/uploadedfiles\/files\/", 
            "file_ext":".jpg", 
            "file_size":27.38, 
            "is_image":true,
            "image_width":479, 
            "image_height":403, 
            "image_type":"jpeg", 
            "image_size_str":"width=\"479\" height=\"403\""

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please elaborate a bit about what this data structure is. Did you read it from a file? A web service? Is it already parsed into an object or array? What did you try? By access, do you mean retrieving the names of the files or reading the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you gave is a json string. First you must decode it and loop over the appointments to use the file names:

```
$result = json_decode($yourJsonString);

foreach ($result->Appointments as $appointment) {
    echo $appointment->file_name;
}
```

Comment: thanx..it works